# Append to Specific Array Index from another table dynamically SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, ssms-2016

I have a json string that I need to modify

```
{"RecordCount":3,"Top":10,"Skip":0,"SelectedSort":"Seed asc","value":[{"AccountProductListId":22091612871138,"Name":"April 4th 2018","AccountId":256813438078643,"IsPublic":false,"Comment":"Test order sheet","Quantity":3},{"AccountProductListId":166305848801939,"Name":"test","AccountId":256813438078643,"IsPublic":false,"Comment":"","Quantity":1},{"AccountProductListId":21177711287586,"Name":"Test Order sheet","AccountId":256813438078643,"IsPublic":true,"Comment":"the very first sheet","Quantity":2}]}
```

Inside value the array looks like this:

```
"value": [{
    "AccountProductListId": 22091612871138,
    "Name": "April 4th 2018",
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Comment": "Test order sheet",
    "Quantity": 3
}, {
    "AccountProductListId": 166305848801939,
    "Name": "test",
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Comment": "",
    "Quantity": 1
}, {
    "AccountProductListId": 21177711287586,
    "Name": "Test Order sheet",
    "IsPublic": true,
    "Comment": "the very first sheet",
    "Quantity": 2
}],
```

What I need to do is append some data from another table:

```
AccountProductListId    ProductID
21177711287586          97096131867163|32721319938943
22091612871138          97096131867163|145461009584740|130005306921282
166305848801939         8744071222157
```

As you can see the AccountProductListId is already in the JSON result so I should know which array it should go to. The only problem is I don't know the syntax to merge the ProductID data into its specific array index. The JSON array could have more than 3 items.

Essentially ending up with something like this:

```
    "value": [{
    "AccountProductListId": 22091612871138,
    "Name": "April 4th 2018",
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Comment": "Test order sheet",
    "Quantity": 3,
    "ProductID": "97096131867163|145461009584740|130005306921282"
}, {
    "AccountProductListId": 166305848801939,
    "Name": "test",
    "IsPublic": false,
    "Comment": "",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "ProductID": "8744071222157"
}, {
    "AccountProductListId": 21177711287586,
    "Name": "Test Order sheet",
    "IsPublic": true,
    "Comment": "the very first sheet",
    "Quantity": 2,
    "ProductID": "97096131867163|32721319938943"
}],
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Process with SQL Server**

Prior to SQL Server 2016, there is not in-built support to read or write JSON.

Starting SQL Server 2016, you can use OPENJSON rowset function to read JSON and FOR JSON clause to write JSON.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

The approach would be to use OPENJSON to read the JSON string as a rowset, join it with the table to pickup ProductID and use FOR JSON to convert back to JSON.

**Process outside SQL Server**

Depending on your situation, it might be simpler to parse JSON outside SQL Server. If going that route, then you could

1. Collect all the AccountProductListIDs from the parsed JSON
2. Send the collected id to SQL Server via a stored procedure that takes a TVP input and outputs the AccountProductListID -> ProductID mapping
3. Inject the ProductIDs into JSON object and serialize back to string